# Generate unique values for global constexpr variables

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am using global constexpr as keys to access a map, and I was wondering if there was a way to automatically initialize them with the next available integer.

```
constexpr size_t ON_EVENT_X = 0;
constexpr size_t ON_EVENT_Y = 1;
constexpr size_t ON_EVENT_Z = 2;
```

Is it possible, given ON_EVENT_X, ON_EVENT_Y and ON_EVENT_Z to automatically initialize them with the correct values ?
I think it could be done with a preprocessor macro but I haven't used it enough to know exactly how.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could use enum, or BOOST_PP_COUNTER macro https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/counter.html

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you wouldn't just do `enum : size_t { ON_EVENT_X, ON_EVENT_Y, ON_EVENT_Z };`? Bonus points for making it an `enum class` and using the enum type as your map key - instant code safety and clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An enum is appropriate for this:

```
enum : std::size_t {
    ON_EVENT_X,
    ON_EVENT_Y,
    ON_EVENT_Z,
};
```

For more complex cases, such as separate definitions or whatever where enum is not appropriate, there are macro based solutions such as `BOOST_PP_COUNTER` combined with `BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know enums could be anonymous

Comment: @V.Aubry It can be preferable to give it a name though, so that you can use it as a variable type which can make the program easier to understand. Otherwise it won't be immediately obvious that the `std::size_t` is supposed to be an event identifier.

Comment: `std::size_t` is a strange choice for an enum -- it's not the size of anything! Why not a regular (signed or unsigned) integer type?

Comment: @TonyK I used `std::size_t` to be consistent with OP. `std::size_t` is commonly used when indexing arrays. Perhaps OP intends to use those values as array indices? I imagine that a smaller type could be sufficient for this though.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry -- I see it wasn't your decision.